# Calculate average daily visitor in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've got some problems calculating my average daily visitors from the MySQL database. I've got a column which is automatically filled with 0 or 1, depending if the visitor is a real visitor or a bot.
My Query looks like this

```
SELECT
   COUNT( * ) / COUNT( DATEDIFF( NOW( ) , 
   SELECT * 
    FROM mw_visitors
    WHERE bot = 0
    ORDER BY ID ASC 
   LIMIT 1 ) )
FROM mw_visitors
WHERE bot = 0
```

But it doesn't work. My PHPMyAdmin tells me, that there is an error in my Syntax at "SELECT * FROM mw_visitors where bot = 0 ORDER..". I've searched in the web, but didnt found the right thing.

EDIT: Structure http://pastebin.com/dm4Hjukr
Getting real, human visitors:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) AS `visits`
FROM `mw_visitors` WHERE `bot` = 0 AND `time` BETWEEN
(SELECT `time` FROM `mw_visitors` WHERE `bot` = 0 ORDER BY `ID` ASC LIMIT 1) AND NOW()
```

Comment: could you please post your data structure, some data example and the expected result (try [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/)) ?

Comment: The internet connection in my school isn't able to complete the requests, but here's my structure:

http://pastebin.com/dm4Hjukr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I saw your table structure. In that case, the query you're looking for should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`ip`)) / (SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),(SELECT `time` FROM `mw_visitors` ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT 1)))) AS `visits` FROM `mw_visitors` WHERE `bot` = 0 AND `time` BETWEEN NOW() AND (SELECT `time` FROM `mw_visitors` ORDER BY `time` ASC LIMIT 1);
```

I didn't checked the last `(SELECT...)` but it should be fine.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, thanks for your help: http://pastebin.com/3T1cUMPD

Answer (score 1):

Having an idea about how do your table looks like would surely help a lot but, even without that, why don't you model the query in a simpler way?

If I understood you correctly, you want to get the number of REAL visitors hitting your website, so you need to filter out any robot.

Isn't is easier to model the query like this?

```
SELECT COUNT(`visitor_id`) AS `visits` FROM `mw_visitors` WHERE `bot` = 0 AND `date` BETWEEN ? AND ?;
```

(being those two question marks the date region you want to check your visitor hits against).

Comment: I've edited my first Post and answered your question.
Is there any more convenient way to answer your Posts (=here named answers) ? This comment functions are not good for posting code.

Comment: Hmmm... right. You need to add `ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),(SELECT `date` FROM `mw_visitors` WHERE `bot` = 0 ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 1)))`